# One-to-many relation with additional field

Tags: sql, orm, prisma

I am creating a schema in prisma with the model User and Guild.

- User can have one guild or none
- Guild can have multiple User

Now I want to add an additional field of the role a user have in the guild.

What would be the best to achieve this?

I could add them to the user but then I have to manage it in the code that all are null or not null.

```js
enum GuildRole {
  MEMBER
  CO_LEADER
  LEADER
}

model Guild {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  users       User[]
}

model User {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  username    String?   @unique

  guild       Guild?    @relation(fields: [guildId], references: [id])
  guildId     Int?
  guildRole   GuildRole?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as following when adding an existing user to a guild.

```
import { PrismaClient, GuildRole } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

// add user to guild
const addAnExistingUserToAGuild = async (userId: number, guildId: number, guildRole: GuildRole) => {
  return await prisma.user?.create({
    data: {
      guildId: guildId,
      userId: userId,
      guildRole: guildRole,
    },
  })
}
```

The modelling will completely depend on your personal/company preference/style, I've modelled your schema like this :

```
enum GuildRole {
  MEMBER
  CO_LEADER
  LEADER
}

model User {
  userId    Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  username  String?    @unique
  guild     Guild?     @relation(fields: [guildId], references: [guildId])
  guildId   Int?
  guildRole GuildRole?
}

model Guild {
  guildId Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name    String
  users   User[]
}
```

More examples in our docs here for how you can create a one-to-many relationship :

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/one-to-many-relations